# T-SQL Between statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, between

I am writing a simple between statement.

```
create table temp(mid int)

insert into temp
values
(1),(2),(3),(4)

select * from temp
where mid between 4 and 1

drop table temp
```

This outputs 1,2,3,4

However I want to use this statement in reverse (I am using this as a simple example in a harder problem). Is there some way I can possibly write BETWEEN 4 and 1? If you try to execute this then an empty dataset will return.

Comment: What do you mean by "in reverse"?  First you state "this outputs 1,2,3,4".  Then you later state "If you try to execute this then an empty dataset will return."  Please be more specific on what on what is happening and what you want.  Does in reverse mean to reverse the order or you want "outside" 4 and 1.

Comment: I think you have oversimplied. Why did you want to use  between 4 and 1 (which should rightly return zero records as it is not possible mathmatically to simulataneously be >= 4 and <= 1). More info about what you are trying to accomplish might help us to point you to the correct solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a range would work for you.

```
IN (4,3,2,1)
```

Another thought, why not use:

```
WHERE mid < 4 and mid > 1
```

or

```
WHERE mid !> 4 and mid !< 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to order your results.

```
SELECT mid
FROM temp
WHERE mid BETWEEN 1 AND 4
ORDER BY mid DESC
```

Alternately, you can use the in function instead:

```
SELECT mid
FROM temp
WHERE mid IN(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: I would never rely on anything but an explicit ordering to return a specific order.  DB2 does not (appear to) guaruntee return order in regards to an `IN()` predicate.

Comment: My first answer was taking a guess at what he/she was looking for. My second example was giving him/her an alternative to answer to his question.

Comment: Any SQL database that is standards compliant will require an ORDER BY to put results in a particular order.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted here? Again, my first suggestion was taking a guess that OP wanted to sort the results. My second suggestion was answering the question as it was stated, hence the lack an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't ever use `BETWEEN`**, it is just easier, more flexible, and clearer just to use `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`.

I'd do this:

```
create table temp(mid int)
insert into temp
values
(1),(2),(3),(4)
select * from temp
where mid<=4 and mid>=1  --same as where mid>=1 and mid<=4
--    ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
drop table temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `X BETWEEN Y AND Z` is equivalent to `X >= Y AND X <= Z`. The built in assumption is that `Y <= Z` and I don't believe there's any way to make BETWEEN work without that assumption.
You can use this as a workaround though:

```
...
WHERE X BETWEEN Y AND Z 
   OR X BETWEEN Z AND Y
```